# When extending a list with extend function without assigning them to memory returning None

Tags: python, python-2.7

when trying to do that it is returning `None`.

```
x = [1,2,3].extend([4,5,6])
```

but `[1,2,3] + [4,5,6]` this is working fine can anybody tell me why?

I mean `extend()` function takes the same format, so why is it returning none?

Comment: `extend` alters the list it is called on in place, and returns `None`. If you want something like `[1,2,3] + [4,5,6]` then use that.

Comment: `x = [1, 2, 3]` then `x.extend(4, 5, 6)` will give you the result.

Comment: `list.extend()` takes other iterables to, while concatenation doesn't. `list.extend()` updates the list object *in place* and returns `None`, do not use it on a literal.

Answer (score 2):

`help(list.extend)` will give you something like below:

```
extend(...)
    L.extend(iterable) -> None -- extend list by appending elements from the iterable
```

So, `extend` do merge two list, but return `None`, as it is an in-place operation. For example:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> print(a.extend([4,5,6]))
None
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```